# No Default.htm in my visual Studio 2019 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to build a Web application in Visual Studio and upload it to my hosting provider (1&1).  I have created a new skeleton ASP.net core application in Visual Studio (2019 community edition). However, the files created do not include a default.htm file.  my Hosting company has a default.htm file in my directory and expects it to be overwritten by the publish.  As Visual studio doesn't upload a default.htm file, the hosted web page just displays the 1&1 default page.  I am sure the answer to this is really simple, but if someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.
Thanks!

Comment: Core doesn't use .htm files.  You need to configure your server for Core.  Configuration depends on whether you're using server side or client side Core.  Perhaps talk to your host technical support to see what the configuration options are?  For example, if it's Windows IIS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks!  I'll go back to host technical support